# My listview with a database is not working

Tags: android, listview

**Hi I have created a list view in my activity,in which I want to display the contents from the database. but an error occured saying there is no list view found Can anybody give me a better solution to overcome the error?**

**my logcat is given below**

```
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675): FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.neochat/com.neochat.Friends_list}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at     
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at     
    android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2023)    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at     
    android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at     
    android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at     
    android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at     
    android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at     
    android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:154)    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at     
    android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at     
    android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at     
    android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at     
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at  
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137   
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at    
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at     
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at    
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at    
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at 
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your   
    content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'    
    08-23 07:04:28.025: E/AndroidRuntime(24675):    at     
    android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
```

**giving my java class below**

```
             public class Friends_list extends ListActivity implements  
                        OnItemClickListener{


        private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

        private String tableName = LoginDataBaseAdapter.tableName;

            private SQLiteDatabase newDB;

           ListView listview;
             Context context;



          @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);
    //listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    openAndQueryDatabase();

    displayResultList();


    context=this;


    //String[] arrayColumns=new String[]{"Name,Username"};
    //int[]arrayViewIDs=new int[] 
             {R.id.textViewSMSSender,R.id.textViewMessageBody};
    //Cursor cursor;

            //cursor.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
             null,null,null,null);
    //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    //SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new 
              SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.friendsms, cursor, arrayColumns, 
              arrayViewIDs);

    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        //   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, android.R.id.text1, 
             value); 

    //listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    //listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
         }


          private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             }

              private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
       try {

          LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter=new     
                      LoginDataBaseAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());
           newDB=loginDataBaseAdapter.getWritableDatabase();
          Cursor c=newDB.rawQuery("  SELECT    NAME   , 
                   USERNAME     FROM    "+ tableName, null);
    if (c != null ) { 
        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                    String Name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
                   String Username=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("USERNAME"));
            }
                 while(c.moveToNext());             
         }
           }
             }
               catch (SQLiteException se) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not open the database");
           }
               finally {
             if(newDB!=null)
        newDB.execSQL("   DELETE    FROM   "+ tableName);
               newDB.close();
                   }
             }

                private void displayResultList() {

         TextView tView = new TextView(this);
            tView.setText("Friends");
            getListView().addHeaderView(tView);
             setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
                    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);


                    }


        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) 
        {

            Intent in2=new   
                 Intent(Friends_list.this,InboxActivity.class);
            startActivity(in2);
        }


                    }
```

**here is my xml codes for displaying list view**

```
         <LinearLayout  
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
              >
             <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list"
         style="@style/WhiteText"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                >
            </ListView>  
           </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`

Answer (score 2):

The `id` for your `listview` should be         `android:id="@android:id/list`

So your xml will look like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        style="@style/WhiteText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yeah dude it works thanks a lot ..but I cannot see any content in my list ..what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are refering to the id as android.R.id.list, I just tested on my listview and dosent finds the id. Use just R.id.list I hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Since you are extending ListActivity,
you can better give like this:

```
listView = getListView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution just extends simple `Activity`

```
public class Friends_list extends ListActivity
```

in onCreate()

```
          @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);
      listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

     // other code here....
   }
```